# Uv unwrapping a bent cylinder shape not working correctly

Tags: mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

Recently I started working on a guitar model and for some extra detail I now want to apply a bump map to the thicker strings to make it look like wounded strings.

[image: Example of what I'm trying accomplish]

Basically they are cylinders ( without the top and bottom faces ) but the unwrapping doesn't work on the whole part of the mesh even though I added seams.

[image]
[image]

I tried every UV unwrapping option in the menu when pressing U, checked the scale and normals but can't find a proper way to just unwrap everything like the top and bottom parts. If anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Cool model! It looks great!

Comment: Thanks! But I want it to be as detailed as I can get it which includes this string  parts. I tried using the screw modifier to make it actual geometry but I ended up with way too much vertices ( no surprise )

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to tell whether you properly marked the needed seams. Possibly the caps of the cylinder you are using for the strings are still there and alter the way it is unwrapped.

Try the following. Build Curve using a Bezier Curve -> Convert to mesh -> Mark seam along length of the mesh -> Unwrap -> Done

[image]

Comment: It already is a mesh and I tried this ( I had one seam the entire length and removed the ones where the cap faces were ) which gives the same result for some reason ( also the same result with the top and bottom seams ) it works fine for the small part at the bottom and the spiral thing at the top but somehow not for the long straight part in the middle

Comment: would you share the blend with just the string in it, maybe i can find where the error evolves from.

Maybe you have corrupt geometry like double vertices, double faces, non-manifold edges etc. - Something has to be different to what I did, since it works for me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B73mDyrlSCcdREN2QnNTXy1VQTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Add loops to the long part of the string so the mesh resolution approximately matches the rest of the string mesh. Unwrap - voilá it works.

I think this is an issue related to area stretch minimization which occurs on very long faces next to angles. There is no solution to unwrapping this shape if you do not have enough subdivisions.

Comment: let that be the only thing I haven't tried. I wanted to try that after nothing else worked to keep geometry count lower but if it works I'll do it.

Comment: it is a give and take. that is true. These are the limits of uv space. If you are interested in other mapping methods you could take a look at ptex or manual uv correction.